# How to use cell contents as range address?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two versions of a workbook that we've run the "compare documents" function on, and therefore have a list of which cells which are different.
We would like to now format just these cells.

How do I use the content of one cell as the range to find on another sheet.

e.g. The content of cell A1 on Sheet1 is "B15". I want to activate cell B15 on Sheet2 (and then format it, and then loop, etc. but it's just that first referencing part I need).

Comment: `Dim addr As String`, `addr = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value`, then `Sheet2.Range(addr)`....

Comment: `B15` is just a string, so `sheet2.Range(sheet1.Range("A1").Value).Activate`

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't get there by myself!